# How to implement conditional search to upper direction from each row using dplyr?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

This is a sample data frame as below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  B=c(1,NA,3,2,NA,4,3),
  C=c(NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA),
  D=c(NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA))

> df
  A  B  C  D
1 1  1 NA NA
2 2 NA  1  2
3 3  3 NA NA
4 4  2 NA NA
5 5 NA  2  4
6 6  4 NA NA
7 7  3 NA NA
```

I want to implement following manipulation using `dplyr` piping function in `R`.

- Adding a new columns `E` which contains `D` in the following conditions.
- Search `!is.na(C)` from each row to upper direction
- If `!is.na(C)`, pad column `E` by a value stored in `D`

This is a desired output.

```
> df2
  A  B  C  D  E
1 1  1 NA NA NA
2 2 NA  1  2 NA
3 3  3 NA NA NA
4 4  2 NA NA NA
5 5 NA  2  4  2
6 6  4 NA NA NA
7 7  3 NA NA NA
```

I prefer to implement upper-directional search using piping function in `dplyr`.
I know a `lag` function in `base` but it does not work for this issue. I also tried to use `slice` function in `dplyr` but it also do not do searching from each row to upper direction.

I hope you could suggest other solutions for this matter.
I tried to use `slice` in `dplyr` but I could not do appropriate filtering from each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can copy the contents of `D` in `E` and use `tidyr::fill` to replace `NA`'s with recent non-NA values and use `lag` to get previous value in `E`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(E = D) %>%
  tidyr::fill(E)  %>%
  mutate(E = replace(lag(E), is.na(D), NA))


#  A  B  C  D  E
#1 1  1 NA NA NA
#2 2 NA  1  2 NA
#3 3  3 NA NA NA
#4 4  2 NA NA NA
#5 5 NA  1  4  2
#6 6  4 NA NA NA
#7 7  3 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a simple solution. It is new to know `fill()` in `tidyr` and it worked perfectly in the sample `df`. I will apply it to the actual data frame.

Answer (score 2):

This uses `bind_rows` to combine the NA `C` values with the non-NA `C` values with your lag criteria:

```
bind_rows(df%>%
            filter(is.na(C))%>%
            mutate(E = NA)
          ,
          df%>%
            filter(!is.na(C))%>%
            mutate(E = lag(D))
          )%>%
  arrange(A)

  A  B  C  D  E
1 1  1 NA NA NA
2 2 NA  1  2 NA
3 3  3 NA NA NA
4 4  2 NA NA NA
5 5 NA  1  4  2
6 6  4 NA NA NA
7 7  3 NA NA NA
```

In [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) this is very simple:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[!is.na(C), E:=shift(D)][]

   A  B  C  D  E
1: 1  1 NA NA NA
2: 2 NA  1  2 NA
3: 3  3 NA NA NA
4: 4  2 NA NA NA
5: 5 NA  1  4  2
6: 6  4 NA NA NA
7: 7  3 NA NA NA
```

Base isn't too bad either:

```
# base
df2 <- df

df2$E <- NA
ind <- !is.na(df2$C)
df2[ind, 'E'] <- df2[ind, 'D'][c(NA,seq_len(sum(ind)-1))]

df2
```

Comment: Thank you for providing comprehensive solutions using several functions. It also gave me a new perspective of data manipulation.